# avoid asking too much information on google's OpenID

Tags: authentication, openid, django-openid-auth

I'm using openID to authenticate a user with google's accounts.

I'm using

```
openid_url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'

('http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/first','firstname')
('http://openid.net/schema/namePerson/last','lastname')
```

but when the user is redirected to google's page, it appears:

> View basic information about your account

and when I click on the info button, it appears:

> View your name, public profile URL, and photo
>
> View your gender and birthdate
>
> View your country, language, and timezone

which is clearly not what I'm asking for.

Why is this happening? How can I avoid losing users because they think I'm Big Brother?

Comment: I have the same issue with my PHP-OpenID request. I suspect that Google knows it *may* receive requests containing more AX values, so just issues a blanket statement, rather than replying with specifics. I blame lazy coding :)